# Refresh swipe up to refresh widget flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-animation

I have an app that gets some data from firebase and than calls a class to display a widget based on the data from firebase. I tried adding a swipe up refresh but i have no idea where to put it and what to to call on refresh. I was trying it using the RefreshIndicator.

Here i will put my code in which it calls the database(firebase) and than creates an widget for each event in the database.

If you need any more information, please feel free to comment. Thank you so much for the help!

```
FutureBuilder(
      
    future: databaseReference.once(),
    builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot<DataSnapshot> snapshot) {
       List lists = [];
        if (snapshot.hasData) {
        lists.clear();

        Map<dynamic, dynamic> values = snapshot.data.value;
        values.forEach((key, values) {
            lists.add(values);
        });
      
        return new ListView.builder(
               primary: false,

          padding: EdgeInsets.only(left:12.0,right:12,bottom: 15,),
            shrinkWrap: true,
            itemCount: lists.length,
            
            itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
            
            if(lists[index]["Status"]== "Active"){;
                return Container(
                  
                  child:EvendWidget(lists[index]["EventImage"], 
      Text(lists[index]["EventName"]).data,
      Text(lists[index]["EventLocation"]+ ", "+lists[index]["EventCounty"] ).data,
      Text(lists[index]["Date"]+ ", "+lists[index]["Time"]+ " - "+lists[index]["Time"]).data,
      Text(lists[index]["Duration"]+ " H").data,
      Text(lists[index]["Genre"]).data,
      Text(lists[index]["Price"]).data,false));}else{return SizedBox.shrink(); };
            });
        }
        return Container(
          margin: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 300),
          child:CircularProgressIndicator());
    }),
```

Answer (score 0):

Do something like this..

```
class HomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: RefreshIndicator(
        onRefresh: () async {
          //write your code here to update the list*********
        },
        child: ListView.builder(
          itemCount: 100,
          itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
            return Text('Line $index');
          }
        )
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: i have to add all of it inside the FutureBuilder or is the FutureBuilder inside

Comment: You have to put RefreshIndicator() inside FutureBuilder()

Comment: and i add the code one the         return new ListView.builder(
 line?

Comment: I don't get you

Comment: i dont understand where i need to place RefreshIndicator and what to put on refresh

Comment: Write a method to pull data from cloud and update the list with latest data. Finally call the method from inside onRefresh()

Comment: for pulling the data is the databaseReference.once(), method?

Comment: Try doing it. You will know better how you are getting data from firebase.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with below lines may be it will work for you

```
return RefreshIndicator(
 color: Colors.blue,
   onRefresh: () {
    Navigator.pushReplacement(
      context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) => HomePage()));
   },
    child: ListView.builder(
            ....
));
```

Comment: i tried adding it like this but id does nothing.. http://dontpad.com/codesss

Comment: Please let me know exactly what you want to achieve

Comment: Ok, so this is how the home page looks: https://gyazo.com/6d1dde536e63ead9b7d21dd5bdc74bea

On refresh, it should call the database again (Refresh the whole page which is all in the code i posted) and put the events again on the list view

Comment: what the code does right now is check the database and for each event in the database, it will create a container in the list view

Comment: do you get any data from a constructor? Means from previous page?

Comment: no, it is all taken from the database (firebase)

Comment: @AndreiMarin you can my answer again i update it

Comment: @AndreiMarin please have a look again at to the same answer and check this will work for you or not

Comment: and do i add the whole future builder inside or do i add it inside the " return new ListView.builder(" line

Comment: no no 
only change your listview code with my answer code remaining part is the same as your answer

Comment: the thing is that nothing happens, it doenst work to swipe up

Comment: l think it has something to do with the future builder

Comment: @AndreiMarin may be

Comment: if you wand we could to  a teamviewer or something to  see what hapens live